# What is wrong in this code?

Tags: bash, osx, array

The code is ;

```
cm=$1
nm=$2
case $cm in
"out")
declare -a  en
declare -a inf
ec=$(grep -n "! " hw1_out_si_wire.txt)
IFS=$'\n' en=($ec)
lst=$((${#en[@]} -1))
IFS=' ' inf=($en[$lst])
echo " Energy: ${inf[4]} ${inf[5]}"
;;
"in") echo "It's not my problem";;
esac
```

And I'm trying to take 7th element of $en but the output is ;

```
[7]ergy: -1090.13343774 Ry
```

And the $en array is ;

```
!    total energy              = -1090.13343774 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.20757070 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.24296462 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.25563488 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.27085564 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.27693129 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.28213580 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.29131927 Ry
```

So, what is the problem with this code ?Why is the output like this ?

Note:If the informations given is not enough , please inform me.

Comment: Could the person who voted against say the reason for it ?

Comment: I tried your code on http://www.shellcheck.net/#, apart from other warnings, it says that "Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element" (https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2128) for this line of code `IFS=' ' inf=($en[$lst])`

Comment: Whenever I see things like `[7]tring` when I'm expecting `somestring [7]` I suspect Windows-style CR-LF line-endings are involved

Comment: @spasic I couldn't understand what you mean.Could you explain ?

Comment: Your input file probably has DOS-style line endings. `dos2unix` it.

Comment: @Mat the file is given me through homework , so I shouldn't change it and also there is no problem reading the file , I checked.

Comment: So what's the problem to pass it through `dos2unix` without modification?

Comment: Ok , I can do it but it is not the problem.I can take the data from the file.The problem starts after that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: By the way , editors of codereview SE says , this post off topic for coderevies SE , so any ideas about  where this post is most appropriate ?

Comment: @Mat By the way , I converted the text file but this time the code totally behaved differently like gone mad :)

Comment: are you required to write your code using mostly shell built-ins, or can you use common shell tools like sed or awk?  (awk would be a far better choice for this task).  Also, is this your code or have you been given this code and asked to fix it?  If you're allowed to use `awk` then please add sample input and output to your question....this is probably an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: e.g.  `awk -F'[\r ]+'  '/^!/ {c++} ; c==7 { print " Energy:",$5,$6 }' hw1_out_si_wire.txt` - this works whether it's a dos text file or unix format.

Comment: @cas I can use whatever I want in a sense.there was not restriction

Comment: OK, that's good.  Does my awk script give you the output you want?  btw the `-F` option wasn't quite right.  The `awk` command should have been: `awk -F'[\r[:blank:]]+' '/!/ {c++} ; c==7 { print " Energy:",$5,$6 }' hw1_out_si_wire.txt`

Comment: @cas The first one give me this error; "awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 /^!/ {c++} ; c==7 { print " Energy:",$5,$6 >>>  }hw1_out_si_wire. <<< txt
awk: bailing out at source line 1"

Comment: @cas And the second one gone mad .output was like ;Energy: -1090.27085564 Ry  Energy: -1090.27085655 Ry  Energy: < 0.00000083  Energy:    Energy: is the  Energy:    Energy: -5526.78042496 Ry  Energy: 2871.21306376 Ry  Energy: -487.26534183 Ry  Energy: 2052.56502088 Ry  Energy: = -0.00317350  Energy:    Energy: achieved   Energy:    Energy: atoms (Ry/au):  Energy:    Energy:    Energy: down): 0.786E-02  Energy: 1 force  Energy: 1 force  Energy: 1 force  Energy: 1 force  Energy: 1 force  Energy: 1 force  Energy: 1 force  Energy: 1 force  Energy: 1 force  Energy: 1 force...

Comment: I think you mistyped my awk script.  it works perfectly on my system.  it looks like you missed the single-quotes on the first version.  dunno what you did on the second, maybe typed `c=7` rather than `c==7`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40724/discussion-between-cas-and-leth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that something is **possible** to do in `bash`, doesn't mean that you should, or that it's a good idea.  What you are trying to do is much easier in languages like `awk` or `perl`.

bash arrays are a fairly advanced usage of bash and, due to limitations in the bash/sh language itself (and the awkwardness of using them), not really as useful as arrays are in other languages.  They're great for passing multiple arguments to a command or a function, but of limited use beyond that.

Instead of messing around with bash arrays, try `awk`.

For example:

```
#! /bin/sh

cm="$1"
nm="$2"

case "$cm" in
  out) awk -F'[[:space:]]+' '
           /^!/  {
             c++;
             if (c==7) {
               print " Energy:",$5,$6;
             };
           };' hw1_out_si_wire.txt ;;

   in) echo "It's not my problem" ;;
esac
```

Output:

```
 Energy: -1090.28213580 Ry
```

The embedded `awk` script counts each line beginning with a `!`, and when it gets to the 7th line, it prints the 5th and 6th fields.

The `-F` option sets the field separator to 1-or-more whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, newlines, carriage returns, form-feeds, and vertical tabs).  The version in my comment used `[\r[:blank:]]+` (which is blank characters, spaces and tabs, plus carriage-return).  For your input data, it works the same.

If your version of `awk` doesn't support regexp field-separators (e.g. `mawk`) then just drop the `-F'[[:space:]]+'` from the `awk` command-line.  It will still work, but if the input file is a MS-DOS/Windows text file (i.e. with carriage-return and line-feed as line-ending) rather than a unix text file (with line-feed only as line-ending), it'll output a carriage-return at the end.  The carriage-return will be invisible unless piped through `cat -v`:

```
 Energy: -1090.28213580 Ry^M
```

In that case, convert the file to unix format with `fromdos` first.

Comment: @leth try the script now, i fixed a bug where it would print all lines it sees while `c==7`, not just those matching `/^!/`.  Again, remove the `-F'[[:space:]]+'` option from the `awk` command line if your `awk` doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you're indexing into the `en` array incorrectly. 
When you index into an array, you have to use braces;
not

```
   $en[$lst]
```

but

```
   ${en[$lst]}
```

Comment: the last element of $en is the first [0] element of $inf this time.