# How can I assign the last element of an array to a another array?

Tags: bash, array

Let say I have an array $Info whose elements are ;

```
!    total energy              = -1090.13343774 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.20757070 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.24296462 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.25563488 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.27085564 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.27693129 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.28213580 Ry
!    total energy              = -1090.29131927 Ry
```

and I want to take its last element , split it with spaces and give to an another array $LastInfo.
How can I do that ?

I tried this;

```
lst=$((${#Info[@]} -1))
IFS=' ' LastInfo=($en[$lst])
```

But as posted in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287410/what-is-wrong-in-this-code) the code doesn't work.

Comment: That is actually still the same problem as your last question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is wrong in this code?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287410/what-is-wrong-in-this-code)

Comment: In last question I asked the mistake in the code but in this one , I am asking how can I do this differently.

Comment: It's the same issue and you're referring to the same code.  Your main error is to think that space delimitation wouldn't count the number of spaces in between the columns.

Comment: @JuliePelletier But when I change the number of spaces in IFS , the result is not changing ?

Comment: Indeed, IFS describes a list of characters to be used as separators, not a string to use.  You need a better approach such as column position since your input appears to be fixed.  Look at `man cut`.

Comment: probably an  [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  You almost certainly want to do this in `awk` or `perl` rather than messing around with bash arrays.

Answer (score 1):

With `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh`

```
last=( "${arr[@]: -1}" )
```

That has the advantage over the zsh-style `last=( "${arr[-1]}" )` (beside being more portable: to ksh93 and to bash 4.2 or older which don't support the zsh-style syntax) that if `$arr` is an empty array, `$last` becomes an empty array as well rather than an array containing one empty element.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is:

```
# given that $Info is a populated array..
Lastinfo=(${Info[-1]})
```

Whitespace is already a default separator, so each space-separated element of the list entry in the `Info` array will be an entry in the new `LastInfo` array.

Comment: Even with this I still taking the first [0] element of $Info

Comment: @DopeGhoti: Um, what?  `${#Info[@]}` is the number of elements in `Info`.  And `${Info[-1]}` doesn't work in bash.

Comment: I didn't notice the octothorpe in the `${#Info[@]}` construct.  And I just tested `${array[-1]}` in `bash` and it worked?  See http://hastebin.com/umedapaqoy.sh

Comment: @Scott negative-subscript-from-end is a newish feature; in my 4.3.11+ on Ubuntu `/usr/share/doc/bash/NEWS.gz` lists it as a change in 4.3 from 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your array is called `Info`,
   and you're calculating the index of the last element of `Info`,
   it doesn't make sense to use it to index into `en` (a different array).
2. When you do index into an array, you have to use braces;
   not

   ```
      $en[$lst]
   ```

   but

   ```
      ${en[$lst]}
   ```